# android how to find version number from file downloaded for FOTA update

Tags: android, download, zip, version, firmware

I want to control firmware upgrade for android rooted devices for specific versions only.

I know that, to update the firmware, after downloading the zip from devices' manufacturer,   call goes to `RecoverySystem.installPackage(Context context, File packageFile)`

There, I'm planning to check the newer version which will be installed on the device i.e. the
firmware version no to which the device will get upgrade to.

So how can I get version information from that downloaded zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
Each FOTA zip contains file named 'metadata' at location "/META-INF/com/android/". The first line in that file contains version information including version no.

You can get that by following code.

```
 /**
 * API to unzip package file and retrieve version no from
 * /META-INF/com/android/metadata file inside zip
 * 
 * @param File
 * 
 * @return String versioNo
 */
private static String getVersion(File packageFile) {
    String versionNo = null;
    if (packageFile != null && packageFile.exists()) {
        String firstLine = getFirstLine(packageFile);
        Log.d(TAG, "in getVersion. firstLine: " + firstLine);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(firstLine) == false) {
            String[] arrStr = firstLine.split("/");
            if (arrStr.length > 1) {
                String[] data = arrStr[2].split(":");
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    return data[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return versionNo;
}

/**
 * API to unzip package file and retrieve first line from
 * /META-INF/com/android/metadata file
 * 
 * @param File
 * 
 * @return String versioNo
 */
private static String getFirstLine(File packageFile) {
    ZipInputStream zin = null;
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream(packageFile.getPath());
        zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                File f = new File(packageFile.getCanonicalPath());
                if (!f.isDirectory()) {
                    f.mkdirs();
                }
            } else {
                String name = ze.getName();
                String[] arr;
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    arr = name.split("/");
                }
                if (arr.length < 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ("metadata".equals(arr[arr.length - 1])) {
                    InputStreamReader isr = null;
                    BufferedReader buf = null;
                    try {
                        isr = new InputStreamReader(zin, "UTF-8");
                        buf = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        return buf.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.getStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (isr != null) {
                            try {
                                isr.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        if (buf != null) {
                            try {
                                buf.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                zin.closeEntry();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (zin != null) {
            try {
                zin.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (fin != null) {
            try {
                fin.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```